# How to detect Samsung S10 5G is running on 5G network?

Tags: android, android-networking, telephony, telecommunication

Android Q added a new network type, NETWORK_TYPE_NR for 5G which is
not available for Android Pie. Recently released Samsung S10 fully supports 5G. It can show 5G icon on the status bar when it is on the 5G network.

Is it possible for a third-party app to know if Android Pie device on a 5G network or not?

Any help will be appreciated.

The following link is the definition for the new network type. It is not available on the Android Pie branch.

- Source code for Pie release
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release-2/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java
- The latest source code that has NETWORK_TYPE_NR
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#2375

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they backported the code from Q to Pie as the logic for 5G was implemented at the end of last year in Q (alpha).
So when using 
`TelephonyManager.getNetworkType()`

you will likely get

> 20 (5G)

**EDIT**

As per comment below: The network type will be **13** so it doesn't solve the thing.

**EDIT**

Try using reflection

```
static boolean isNRConnected(TelephonyManager telephonyManager) {
    try {
        Object obj = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName())
                .getDeclaredMethod("getServiceState", new Class[0]).invoke(telephonyManager, new Object[0]);

        Method[] methods = Class.forName(obj.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals("getNrStatus") || method.getName().equals("getNrState")) {
                method.setAccessible(true);
                return ((Integer) method.invoke(obj, new Object[0])).intValue() == 3;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No, it returns 13 (LTE) as any phone running in Pie.

Comment: Do you have this phone and 5G coverage? You can try to invoke method `getNrStatus` from ServiceState class. If this return `3` then 5G should be connected.

Comment: There is no such method `getNrStatus` in ServiceState class, not even in Android Q. The code will not compile.

Comment: You need to use reflection.

Comment: Managed to get a SM-G977, the above sample code does work. This is the correct answer! BTW, how do you extract source code from the firmware? @Pavel Machala

Comment: Don't use reflection, Android does not recommend it, they are also forcing this through native sdk interfaces

Comment: You are right that using PhoneStateListener and onDisplayInfo callback is the preferred way in Android 11. However using the reflection was proposed for Android 9 and 10. It seems to work in Samsung devices but other manufacturers used different implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official documentation to detect 5G on Android 11.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features/5g#detection

Call `TelephonyManager.listen()`, passing in `LISTEN_DISPLAY_INFO_CHANGED`, to determine if the user has a 5G network connection.

Answer (score 1):

as @Hunter suggested you need to use "listen" from telephony manager but if it's api 30+ you need to have `READ_PHONE` permission granted and listen for `LISTEN_DISPLAY_INFO_CHANGED` and override `onDisplayInfoChanged` from `PhoneStateListener`

```
(context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager).listen(customPhoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DISPLAY_INFO_CHANGED)
```

The listener should be something like this:

```
private  class CustomPhoneStateListener : PhoneStateListener() {
    override fun onDisplayInfoChanged(telephonyDisplayInfo: TelephonyDisplayInfo) {
               
                super.onDisplayInfoChanged(telephonyDisplayInfo)
              
                    when (telephonyDisplayInfo.overrideNetworkType) {
                         //5G
                        OVERRIDE_NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_ADVANCED_PRO,
                        OVERRIDE_NETWORK_TYPE_NR_NSA,
                        OVERRIDE_NETWORK_TYPE_NR_NSA_MMWAVE -> setNetworkChange(NETWORK_TYPE_NR)
                        OVERRIDE_NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA -> {
                            setNetworkChange(19) //LTE+
                        }
                        else -> setNetworkChange(telephonyDisplayInfo.networkType)
                    }
                } else {
                    setNetworkChange(telephonyDisplayInfo.networkType)
                }
            }

   }
```

Link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features/5g#detection

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted the **ServiceState.java** from SM-G977N firmware and it confirms that they have added 
`ServiceState.getNrStatus()`

5G(NR) is active is if NetworkRegistrationState.NR_STATUS_CONNECTED = 3;

Comment: The reflection trick has been dead since Pie, see https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces.

Comment: Not true. You can still use reflection on public methods. If using reflection on private/protected method/fields then you are in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't add this as a comment, but as @Pavel Machala said, looking at the [ServiceState class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/205886d28f017195963d8922d7ec813309506179/telephony/java/android/telephony/ServiceState.java) in the AOSP yields the following:

```
/**
 * Get the NR 5G status of the mobile data network.
 * @return the NR 5G status.
 * @hide
 */
public @NRStatus int getNrStatus() {
    final NetworkRegistrationState regState = getNetworkRegistrationState(
            NetworkRegistrationState.DOMAIN_PS, AccessNetworkConstants.TRANSPORT_TYPE_WWAN);
    if (regState == null) return NetworkRegistrationState.NR_STATUS_NONE;
    return regState.getNrStatus();
}
```