# Firebase test lab running test with mobile data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I need to identify the current connection type (etc 3G, 4G, 5G). I've used the ConnectivityManager but on some phones, the reported connection is 4G even if the download speed is so big that the phone is clearly on 5G.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598359/how-to-detect-samsung-s10-5g-is-running-on-5g-network) I found a possible way to fix it. I need to check it on different devices.

I was wondering whether there is a way to use Firebase test-lab to do it. I used Firebase test-lab in the past but I was always mocking the network connection to run instrumentation tests so I don't know whether it is possible to actually use a cellular connection and whether it is possible to choose the SIM card used.

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion I'm using `gloud beta`. I run `gcloud firebase test network-profiles list` and I have got the following list:

```
┌────────────┐
│ PROFILE_ID │
├────────────┤
│ LTE        │
└────────────┘
    ┌──────┬────────┬────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬───────┐
    │ RULE │ DELAY  │ LOSS_RATIO │ DUPLICATION_RATIO │ BANDWIDTH │ BURST │
    ├──────┼────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼───────┤
    │ up   │ 0.040s │ 0.001      │                   │ 16000.0   │       │
    │ down │ 0.040s │ 0.001      │                   │ 16000.0   │       │
    └──────┴────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┴───────┘
┌────────────┐
│ LTE-poor   │
└────────────┘
    ┌──────┬────────┬────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬───────┐
    │ RULE │ DELAY  │ LOSS_RATIO │ DUPLICATION_RATIO │ BANDWIDTH │ BURST │
    ├──────┼────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼───────┤
    │ up   │ 0.060s │ 0.0015     │                   │ 4000.0    │       │
    │ down │ 0.060s │ 0.0015     │                   │ 4000.0    │       │
    └──────┴────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┴───────┘
┌────────────┐
│ HSPA       │
└────────────┘
    ┌──────┬────────┬────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬───────┐
    │ RULE │ DELAY  │ LOSS_RATIO │ DUPLICATION_RATIO │ BANDWIDTH │ BURST │
    ├──────┼────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼───────┤
    │ up   │ 0.060s │ 0.001      │                   │ 2000.0    │       │
    │ down │ 0.060s │ 0.001      │                   │ 4000.0    │       │
    └──────┴────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┴───────┘
┌────────────┐
│ HSPA-poor  │
└────────────┘
    ┌──────┬────────┬────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬───────┐
    │ RULE │ DELAY  │ LOSS_RATIO │ DUPLICATION_RATIO │ BANDWIDTH │ BURST │
    ├──────┼────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼───────┤
    │ up   │ 0.100s │ 0.0015     │                   │ 500.0     │       │
    │ down │ 0.100s │ 0.0015     │                   │ 1000.0    │       │
    └──────┴────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┴───────┘
...
```

5G is not in the list (yet). And the result is the same with `gcloud beta firebase test network-profiles list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices in Firebase Test Lab are connected via WiFi by default. There's no guarantee that a device has a SIM at all, and you should not rely on that. Your best choice is to use a specific network profile, which can be configured as part of the test.

You can list all available network profiles and their settings with the command below:

```
$ gcloud firebase test network-profiles list
```

You can set the network profile by using gcloud beta, as the setting is not GA yet:

```
$ gcloud beta firebase test android run \
      --network-profile=LTE \
      <your other args>
```

Comment: Please also note that the `--network-profile` option only works with physical devices and not with virtual devices.

Comment: This is what I need. The test must run on physical devices. The question is only if this is already working now since it is a beta. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it is available for everyone to use.