# Detect 5G connection on Android phone

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm trying to identify the type of cellular connection.
I've used different methods, like for example the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975119/987753), but I keep getting 4G as a result, on a Samsung with Android 10 and 5G connection.
How is it possible to read the correct network type?

```
private fun getNetworkType(telephonyManager: TelephonyManager): String {
    return when (telephonyManager.networkType) {
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN -> "unknown"

        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM -> "2G"

        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA -> "3G"

        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE,
        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN -> "4G"

        TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR -> "5G"

        else -> "something else"
    }
}

private fun getRadioTechnology(telephonyManager: TelephonyManager): String {
    try {
        val obj = Class.forName(telephonyManager.javaClass.name)
                .getDeclaredMethod("getServiceState", *arrayOfNulls(0)).invoke(telephonyManager, *arrayOfNulls(0))
        val methods: Array<Method> = Class.forName(obj.javaClass.name).declaredMethods
        for (method in methods) {
            if (method.name == "getRadioTechnology" ) {
                method.isAccessible = true
                val radioTechnology = (method.invoke(obj) as Int).toInt()
                return "$radioTechnology"
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Test5G", "", e)
    }
    return ""
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun getActiveSubscriptionInfoList(): String {
    val subscriptionInfos = SubscriptionManager.from(this).activeSubscriptionInfoList
    var ret: String = ""
    for(sub in subscriptionInfos) {
        val id = sub.subscriptionId
        val telephonyManager = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(id);
        ret += getRadioTechnology(telephonyManager)
    }
    return ret
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Samsung S10 5G is running on 5G network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598359/how-to-detect-samsung-s10-5g-is-running-on-5g-network)

Comment: No it doesn't. I have actually linked that answer in my question. It does not always work.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have the same issue :/

Comment: @Javier please find the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
telephonyManager.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
    override fun onServiceStateChanged(serviceState: ServiceState) {
        val isNrAvailable = serviceState.toString().isNrAvailable()
        // use isNrAvailable
    }
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE)
```

Where

```
fun String.isNrAvailable() =
        contains("nrState=CONNECTED") ||
        contains("nsaState=5"))
```

Comment: NR State is now masked in Android 12